# Search a JSON object and return a key one level up from a given key:value?

Tags: javascript, json

This feels like a basic question but I'm new to coding and I just can't find the answer. (I have Googled and searched StackOverflow many times.)

Here's a JSON object:

```
const json = {
    "catalog:aardvark": {
        "severity": "minor"
    },
    "catalog:baboon": {
        "severity": "minor",
        "testDependency": "dashboard:echidna"
    },
    "catalog:capybara": {
        "severity": "minor",
        "testDependency": "dashboard:ferret"
    },
    "dashboard:dingo": {
        "severity": "minor"
    },
    "dashboard:echidna": {
        "severity": "minor"
    },
    "dashboard:ferret": {
        "severity": "minor"
    }
}
```

Using vanilla JavaScript or ES6 or a Node module, I need to return the key `"catalog:capybara"` but the only inputs I can use are the key `"testDependency"` and/or the value `"dashboard:ferret"`. All the rest are unknown for these purposes.

I have tried many things to no avail and I'll spare you the details of my failures. Again, this seems like it *should* be simple. I greatly appreciate the help!

PS: Don't be confused by the fact that many of the keys and values include the character `:`

Comment: [There's no such thing as a "JSON Object"](http://benalman.com/news/2010/03/theres-no-such-thing-as-a-json/) nor is this [JSON](http://json.org) (`const json = { ... }`) - that's an object.

Comment: This is an unclear question. If you need to return a specific key, and you already know it, why would you need to return it? Furthermore, if you can only input "testDependency", since several keys have testDependency as a child, there is nothing unique to identify the key you are searching for.

Comment: please add some use cases for nested search and wanted results.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could get the keys of the object and find the nested object, then return the key.

```js
function find(object, key, value) {
    return Object.keys(object).find(k => object[k][key] === value);
}

var object = { "catalog:aardvark": { severity: "minor" }, "catalog:baboon": { severity: "minor", testDependency: "dashboard:echidna" }, "catalog:capybara": { severity: "minor", testDependency: "dashboard:ferret" }, "dashboard:dingo": { severity: "minor" }, "dashboard:echidna": { severity: "minor" }, "dashboard:ferret": { severity: "minor" } };

console.log(find(object, 'testDependency', 'dashboard:ferret'));
```

Comment: OMG, so simple, so spot on. I feel like a true newb that I couldn't get it done. THANK YOU!!

Comment: don't forget to mark this as the answer if it solved your issue ;)

Answer (score 1):

You could map the JSON to an array of keys/values like so:

```
const array = Object.keys(json).map((key) => {
    return  {key: key, value: json[key] };
});
```

You could then filter on the keys/values:

```
const filtered = array.filter((obj) => {
    return obj.key === "catalog:capybara" || obj.value.testDependency === "dashboard:ferret";
});
```